# Connection refused to PostgreSQL server (I have two port but it always goes to default)

Tags: postgresql, port, psycopg2

I am currently setting up a postreSQL server on my Windows computer.(i have 32 bit and 64 bit postgresql)

when I use the (32bits,port is 5433) python to add some data to the database, it gets the following error:

```
    File "C:\Python27\lib\site-packages\psycopg2\__init__.py", line 164, in connection

   conn = _connect(dsn, connection_factory=connection_factory, async=async)
perationalError: could not connect to server: Connection refused (0x0000274D/10
61)
       Is the server running on host "localhost" (::1) and accepting
       TCP/IP connections on port 5432?
ould not connect to server: Connection refused (0x0000274D/10061)
       Is the server running on host "localhost" (127.0.0.1) and accepting
       TCP/IP connections on port 5432?
```

I do write this before adding data to the database

```
conn=psycopg2.connect("dbname='your_database',user='user', password='password','host'='127.0.0.1','port'='5433')
```

but it doesn't work~~
thanks!!

Comment: Did you start the postgresql server?

Comment: Yes,@sebenalern,but I want to use port 5433, instead of 5432

Answer (score 0):

You are mixing up your connect() arguments. The "dbname" signals you are using a libpq url, so a single string argument.

http://initd.org/psycopg/docs/module.html

Try fixing that and see if it does the job.